# How To Mirror Interpolation Mode

Tags: animation, dopesheet

I want to mirror my interpolation mode, how can I do that?

I have:

[image]

What I want (white thick line)

[image]

Comment: What kind of interpolation do your points have ?

Comment: it is exponential....but hopefully there is a solution for all interpolation modes to flip...? ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open the <kbd>N</kbd> Panel in the graph editor and go to the F-Curve sub-panel.

Change the *Easing* Type of the left keyframe from *Ease In* to *Ease Out*.

Alternatively, while the left keyframe is selected, *Right-Click > Easing Type > Ease Out*.

Another solution, use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> > Ease Out while the left keyframe is selected.

Ease In:

[image]

Ease Out:

[image]

Comment: perfect, thank you!